# view flipper example for android in xml parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

hi i am a new app developer. i am trying out a new app working by flip.
I have an xml file of the following format

gcsgacghascgh
abdvdb

At first look it must shows the question and when flipped it must show the answer. this must be done for arount 40 questions.

pls help me by giving any example codes or idea....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FrameLayout. In the framelayout you have to keep 2 layouts. In the first layout you have to keep the question and in the second layout you have to keep the view for showing the answer.

Here [Android 3d Flip Animation](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) is a nice example for the flip animation using FrameLayout. The example is shown with 2 images. You have to just use your layout instead of images.